# Windows and forms authentication in a single app MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, forms, hybridauth

I have a MVC 4 application and I need to authenticate using windows authentication initially.
Display **log in** screen in case of user browsing the website on the hosted server itself.
If accessing remotely, then automatically take windows authentication.
I was thinking:
**a)** Configure the website to use windows authentication 
**b)** Check the IP address of the server and the users IP address
**c)** If they match then display 'log in' screen
**d)** If they don't match then automatically authenticate using windows
I am using MVC 4, sql express and IIS express 7.5, windows 7, VS 2013
***Please advice***
**1)** Is this the best approach for my needs?
**2)** How to achieve this type of authentication where in we need windows and then forms?
***Please Note :*** My log in screen will take userID and password and this is not authenticated against a database, it is just  password validation on the fly using Hash algorithm. We are not storing the user credentials in the database.
I need to add roles as well for this website
If the user is entering the website using log in screen, then they are temp users(operator role) and windows authenticated users are in certain roles(admin, manager,lead etc)
Any pointers will be really helpful.

Thanks
DotNet

Comment: If you are not authenticating passwords against a database, what are you authenticating them against?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to read my question. I am using hash algorithm to generate the password and it is authenticated on the fly.  it was a requirement for me to not store the temp users in database and instead authenticate them on the fly

Comment: OK, but to validate a password you need to compare it to something, whether you hash it or otherwise. What are you comparing it to?

Comment: Also, windows authentication for remote users implies that the user is logged in to the same network the server is on. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

I figures out a way to do this. I set the authentication mode as windows in web.config file

Then I am checking if the user is in AD or not, if not then I am displaying login screen.

I will paste the code a little later, once it is stable so it might benefit someone.